# Subscribe to ServerSentEvents in php

Tags: php, eventsource

I have an endpoint which publishes events, I want my php API to subscribe to the events and trigger responses. Is it possible? I know in nodejs I could use the Eventsource library to subscribe to an endpoint. What's the equivalent in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

SSE is a nice simple text-based protocol, so I would use either the PHP socket functions, or the curl functions. The curl commandline tool is a great way to test an SSE feed. I think you might need to use the `curl_multi_select()` and `curl_multi_getcontent()` functions, even if just fetching from one data source. (If using the low-level PHP socket functions directly you will need to do your own chunking support.)

Alternatively, the Guzzle library might be a higher-level library. I can see in the documentation there is a stream option: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#stream   I've not tried that, so I'd be interested to hear if it works well for you.